# Input type range webkit-slider-thumb background color won't change in ios safari?

Tags: html, css, ios, safari, pseudo-element

I came across an issue when implementing input type range on my site, i tried to set the background color for the -webkit-slider-thumb to be transparent, but it is not working on the ios device (iphone and ipad) safari, the safari inspector still showing the user agent style instead of the style i already implement in my css and inline html file, here the css style i implement in my css file and inline html:

**html file**

```
<input class="slider" list="steplist" max="100" name="range" type="range" value ="0" />
```

**css file**

```
input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-thumb, 
input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-thumb:active{
    background-color: transparent !important;
}
```

here is the screencap for the inspector element  (i inspected it on ipad os safari):
[image]

I noticed date the `background-color` of `input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-thumb` value is still white (following user-agent default style) and not following my css file which is transparent

Comment: Your code doesn't contain any any resets like `input[type="range"]{-webkit-appearance: none}` without these, the browser will stick to the default/agent input styles

Answer (score 5):

According to my analysis, adding a bit of JS should give you the desired output. I have been managed to make -webkit-slider-thumb 's `background: transparent;` even though my approach comes along with a bit of JavaScript. This appears perfectly on iOS; in fact, what you see as preview will be what other devices get.

IOS (Safari) Previews:
[iPhone 14](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iE3dT.png) | [iPhone 14 Plus](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qEBg6.png) | [iPhone 13](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2WvHC.png) | [iPhone 12 Mini](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RxnqF.png)

Other (Chrome) Previews: [Samsung Galaxy S22](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1b10e.png) | [Pixel 7 Pro](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TouO4.png)

This pen helped me to figure out the solution: https://codepen.io/tippingpointdev/pen/bGgLqLY

```js
//Assign input range's id into variable
const range = document.querySelector('#r-input'); 

function rangeOnChange(e) {
  let t = e.target
  
  //Assign range input's properties into variables
  const min = t.min; 
  const max = t.max;  
  const val = t.value;  
  
  /* Adjust range progress as the thumb moves while avoiding overflows */
  t.style.backgroundSize = (val - min) * 89 / (max - min) + '% 100%'; 
}

//Trigger function on thumb move
range.addEventListener('input', rangeOnChange);

/* Adjust range progress at start */
range.style.backgroundSize = (range.value - range.min) * 89 / (range.max - range.min) + '% 100%';
```

```css
input[type="range"] {
  
  /* To hide ordinary range input */
  -webkit-appearance: none;

  margin-right: 15px;
  height: 7px;
  background: lightgray;
  border-radius: 5px;
  
  /* Range progress background is set */
  background-image: linear-gradient(gray,gray);
  background-size: 70% 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

/* Thumb styles */
input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-thumb {

  /* To hide ordinary thumb */
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  
  /* Since range input is created manually, thumb background can be vary in color */
  background: transparent; 
  border: 1px solid gray;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: background .3s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<!-- Since some JS is used, an Id is added here -->
<input id='r-input' type="range" value="70" min="0" max="100" /><p><small>Try moving transparent thumb to see range progress</small></p>
```